# img stretch through 100% of container's height - howto

Tags: html, css

i actually thought that i knew how to do this but now i do have some problems.
img is contained in div#slider which width is 50% of a page's width and height is 450px.

```
img{
width:95%;
height:77%;
}
```

width works just fine, but height is constantly same. ???

page is [HERE](http://lookaroundyou.net) (it is 1st post, jquery gallery)

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Could you make a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: well it obvious to me that it is not 77% of container's height.

Comment: @why screenshot i gave you link to the page. that is not 77% of 450px

Comment: The only element I see on your page with 77% height is `#slider`. The images within have a height of 400px in their style attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nivo slider automatically adjusts the size to the size of the uploaded images. Just upload properly sized images and the slider will automatically wrap around them.

There is some javascript included with the Nivo Slider to do all of this work for you, it is most likely conflicting with your img CSS.

Easiest solution? Upload proper image sizes and let the slider dictate the size.